# Finding length of side

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to refresh my math with self-study, but i'm stuck with the following question. Hope someone can help me with the first steps in solving this.

[image: Finding length of side]

Ps. The book says the answer should be $3 \sqrt{29}$

Comment: If $DE=x$, then $DB^2 = x^2-6^2$, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Pythagorean theorem, $$CD^2+BD^2=BC^2=15^2,$$ and $$BE^2+BD^2=DE^2=AD^2=AC^2-CD^2.$$ From the first equlity, we have that $BD^2=225-CD^2$, then putting it into the second one, we have that $BE^2-CD^2+225=AC^2-CD^2$. So $AC^2=BE^2+225=36+225=261$, which implies that $AC=3\sqrt{29}$.